# Excel VBA dropdownlist per row if value in AColumn

Tags: vba, excel

I´ve been searching for a solution to create a dropdownlist in ColumnC (with start from row 2) if there is value in ColumnA same row.
But all I was able to find is how to create one dropdownlist using VBA.

```
Sub DVraschwab()
  Dim myList$, i%
  myList = ""
  For i = 1 To 7
      myList = myList & "ListItem" & i & ","
  Next i
  myList = Mid(myList, 1, Len(myList) - 1)
  With Range("A5").Validation
      .Delete
      .Add _
      Type:=xlValidateList, _
      AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
      Formula1:=myList
  End With
End Sub
```

Is this possible? And how should I begin?

The dropdownlist should contain "Yes" and "No" and No would be standard.

This is code that execute when I have written anythins in A Col:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  Application.EnableEvents = False 'to prevent endless loop
  On Error GoTo Finalize 'to re-enable the events

  For Each columnAcell In Target.Cells
      columnAcell.Offset(0, 3) = Mid(columnAcell, 2, 3)
      If IsEmpty(columnAcell.Value) Then columnAcell.Offset(0, 4).ClearContents
  Next

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
  Dim c As Range, FR As Variant

  Set w1 = Workbooks("Excel VBA Test.xlsm").Worksheets("AP_Input")
  Set w2 = Workbooks("Excel VBA Test.xlsm").Worksheets("Datakom")

  For Each c In w1.Range("D2", w1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
      FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns("A"), 0)
      If IsNumeric(FR) Then c.Offset(, 1).Value = w2.Range("B" & FR).Value
  Next c

  Call Modul1.DVraschwab
      If Target.Column = 1 Then
      If Target.Value = vbNullString Then
          Target.Offset(, 2).Clear
      End If
  End If

  Finalize:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The module I call is the dropdown you helped me with:

```
Sub DVraschwab()
  Dim myList As String, r As Range

  myList = "Yes,No"

  For Each r In Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
      If r.Value <> vbNullString Then
          With r.Offset(, 2).Validation
              .Delete
              .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=myList
          End With
          r.Offset(, 2).Value = Split(myList, ",")(1)
      End If
  Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this? You basically just need a loop added to your code to check column A.

```
    Sub DVraschwab()

    Dim myList As String, r As Range

    myList = "Yes,No"

    For Each r In Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If r.Value <> vbNullString Then
            With r.Offset(, 2).Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=myList
            End With
            r.Offset(, 2).Value = Split(myList, ",")(1)
        End If
    Next r

    End Sub

'this in the relevant sheet module

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 1 and target.row>1 Then
        If Target.Value = vbNullString Then
            Target.Offset(, 2).Clear
        End If
    End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Yes that´s almost all I wanted, thanks! Two more questings though.

Is it possible to clear the cell in ColumnC so that the Dropdown is gone if I delete the value in A?
I´ve tried "If IsEmpty(columnAcell.Value) Then columnAcell.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents" but the dropdown is still there but blank.

Can I make No as standard value so it is set the moment the dropdown is created for that row?

Comment: I've amended the code above to set the value ot No (as per Variatus). The second bit goes in the sheet module and will clear C if A is cleared. The first bit though is not dynamic so you might want to make that a similar event module.

Comment: Perfect thanks! 
The only issue now is that when I deleted the last instance of value in ColumnA it place a dropdown in ColumnC Row 1 where I have the header.
It doesn´t mather which row I delete the value in Column A.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Are you saying that when you delete a value in col A, it adds a dropdown in col C? Do you have any other code present?

Comment: I updated my question with all my code.
When I delete a vlue in A Col it removes the dropdown i C Col but when the last value in A Col is deleted it creates a Dropdown in C Col row 1 which is the header.

Comment: Sounds odd. Have a small change to my change event code, can you see if that makes a difference.

Comment: No sorry. It failes to remove the dropdown if I mark multiple in A Col. And Header is changed to a dropdown when I remove the last one in A Col.

Comment: Does it matter irrespective of where the last value is in column A?

Comment: Yes no mather where the last value is in column A

Comment: Just noticed a small typo in DVraschwab which may cause the problem (though I doubt it). Can you try (should be <> instead of >).

Comment: I changed to <> instead of > here: If r.Value <> vbNullString Then.
Still same issue. I can´t remove multiple at the same time and the last one I remove changes header to a dropdown.

Comment: I'll have to look at later. In the meantime, set a breakpoint and step through the code and see if you can work out what's happening. Nothing jumps out at me.

Comment: I´ve tried multipple things know and found out that even if I remove the code that it would clear C cell when A i cleared the problem occures. When I delete the last value in A it creates a dropdown list in C1. I also notised that if I change the value in the dropdown to "Yes" for some rows and then add more  values in A Column it will change back to "No". Is it possible to add some check that if C contains value then don´t overwrite?

Comment: I saw that you had accepted the answer and assumed you had sorted it. I suggest you start a new question, post all the code you have and outline the problem as above, and all steps you have taken to identify any problems, even if unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

This code will set the validation and write the default value in each cell.

```
Sub DVraschwab()
    ' 10 Jan 2018

    Const MyList As String = "Yes,No"

    Dim Rl As Long, R As Long

    With Worksheets("Duplicates")            ' replace with your sheet's name
        ' change column from "A" if not applicable
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For R = 2 To Rl
            With .Cells(R, 3).Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                     AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                     Formula1:=MyList
            End With
            .Cells(R, 3).Value = Split(MyList, ",")(1)
        Next R
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This one doesn´t create a dropdown. Nothing happends when I ad values in A column.